# how to put a custom field value in variable

Tags: custom-field, functions, variables, scripts

```
function zh_get_invoice_round_off_number() 
    {
        global $post;
        return get_post_meta($post->ID, 'invoice_round_off_number', true);
    }

    function zh_invoice_round_off_number() 
    {
        echo zh_get_invoice_round_off_number();
    }
```

Comment: Please explain your problem. This is not a good question. See [ask]

Comment: @toscho he edited the question wrongly , i got his question. user2506619 When editing the question dont remove previous content and explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the loop :

```
$custom_fields = get_post_custom(the_ID());
$my_custom_field = $custom_fields['zh_invoice_round_off_number'];
convert_number((int)$my_custom_field);
```

Or with your function :

```
$custom_value = zh_get_invoice_round_off_number();
echo convert_number( (int) $custom_value );
```

Comment: it is not working @Tolea Bivol

Comment: Do you get the custom field value at all ? If yes then : The value doesn't get converted in words ?

Comment: yes the value doesn't get converted in words .@Tolea Bivol

Comment: if i do **echo convert_number('zh_invoice_round_off_number();');** the value get echo but doest convert in word. @Tolea Bivol

Comment: You can't call a function in an another function. First place the result in a variable then pass it as a parameter : `$custom_value = zh_invoice_round_off_number(); echo convert_number($custom_value);`

Comment: Also make sure that you pass `zh_invoice_round_off_number();` as a number not string `convert_number((int) $custom_value);` .

Comment: its still  not working can u please put the changes in the script i may be editing the changes in wrong way .@Tolea Bivol

Comment: see my edited answer

Comment: its still like that .it showing the number only. @Tolea Bivol

Comment: make `var_dump($custom_value);`, and tell me what you get.

Comment: i get null.@Tolea Bivol

Comment: Then the problem is in your `zh_invoice_round_off_number()` function or the custoim field is not set. Edit your question and paste the code of this function in it.

Comment: Make `var_dump(zh_invoice_round_off_number());` and tell me what you get.

Comment: its null.@Tolea Bivol

Comment: Then your `zh_invoice_round_off_number()` function is not working or the specific custom field is not set.

Comment: but when i use it normaly its shows the correct value.@Tolea Bivol

Comment: Where are you calling it ? Show me function , edit your question and add this function's code.

Comment: i updated the function . .@Tolea Bivol

Comment: I see , you must not echo when you use the function as a variable in another function . Use the get function instead. Look at my edited answer.